# part of string value in black list array spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a black list like this.

```
val blacklist: Array[String]=Array("one of a kind", "one of the", "industry leading", "industry's", "industry leader", "lifetime", "#1 ", "number 1", "number one", "Guarantee", "guaranteed", "guarantees", "Compete", "Competes", "competing", "Competed", "competitor", "competitors", "competition", "competitions", "competitive", "competitor's")
```

and I have a dataframe like this

```
+------+---------------------------------+
|name  | value                           |
+------+---------------------------------+
|atr1  | this is one of  a kind product  |
|atr2  | this product is industry leader |
|atr3  | it is competitor's nightmare    |
+------+---------------------------------+
```

I want to filter all the value which is present in black list.

in above case all the result will come.

```
+------+---------------------------------+
|name  | value                           |
+------+---------------------------------+
|atr1  | this is one of  a kind product  |
|atr2  | this product is industry leader |
|atr3  | it is competitor's nightmare    |
+------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `dataframe` as

```
+----+-------------------------------+
|name|value                          |
+----+-------------------------------+
|atr1|this is one of a kind product  |
|atr2|this product is industry leader|
|atr3|it is competitor's nightmare   |
|atr4|testing for filter             |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

You can define `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def blackListFilter = udf((value: String) => blacklist.map(value.contains(_)).toSeq.contains(true))
```

and call it to meet your needs

```
df.filter(blackListFilter($"value"))
```

You should get

```
+----+-------------------------------+
|name|value                          |
+----+-------------------------------+
|atr1|this is one of a kind product  |
|atr2|this product is industry leader|
|atr3|it is competitor's nightmare   |
+----+-------------------------------+
```